.Net Maui Blazor Hybrid: Error when build to IOS target, appsettings.json would result in a file outside of the app bundle and cannot be used
I got the issue appsettings.json : error : The path '../../../../../../../../../Users/xxxxx/Projects/SalesMauiSource/SalesMauiApp/appsettings.json' would result in a file outside of the app bundle and cannot be used. When build .net maui blazor hybid for IOS on Visual Studio Code in Mac Os.
Can you support me resolve it? Thanks you!
You can review this issue on Github: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17078


That is an issue on the GitHub and you can follow it up. You can provide the information about the vs version and how to reproduce the issue.

@GuangyuBai-MSFT I use the latest version of visual studio code on MacOS. I run the debug on target IPad device then it build fail. The issue track on github is still open. You can review my screen-shot about error message on github issue.

You can follow this issue up and wait for the update on the GitHub. It is recommended to post If you have any other information to share.
